# Google firebase analytics plugin for unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase

Google recently launched firebase analytics for iOS and android, which is great and I want to use it in my android game made in unity3d 5.4b19. I tried to build a plugin for this in android studio following this [link](http://www.thegamecontriver.com/2015/04/android-plugin-unity-android-studio.html). I have successfully build the jar, imported in unity, and build an apk file. But when I try to initialize firebase analytics I get following errors

```
AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics;

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics;
```

Here is my main activity class from android studio

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;
import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics;

public class MainActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity {
    private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;

    public void init() {
        // [START shared_app_measurement]
        // Obtain the FirebaseAnalytics instance.
        mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        // [END shared_app_measurement]
    }

    public void setUserProperty(String Property, String value) {
        // [START user_property]
        mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty(Property, value);
        // [END user_property]
    }

    public void logCustomEvent(MenuItem item) {
        // [START custom_event]
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("image_name", "name");
        params.putString("full_text", "text");
        mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("share_image", params);
        // [END custom_event]
    }

    public void logEvent(String id, String name, String type) {
        // [START image_view_event]
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, id);
        bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, name);
        bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, type);
        mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
        // [END image_view_event]
    }

    public void shareText(String subject, String body) {
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
    }
}
```

I understand that this is not working because it cannot find the firebase classes. I don't know how to include these files in my project. I have tried to find jar files for firebase analytics, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: I need to try this to be sure but you need the classes from firebase-analytics.aar and it's dependencies. This should be possible but it will take some effort to get everything setup correctly.

Comment: I recommend now using the official SDK https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update 31/11/16

[Now you can do this from this unitypackage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup)

I extracted all required jar file from SDK folder. It is all there inside Extra folder. Now it is working perfectly fine.

Update: Few people have requested me to post the whole process. So here is the overview of how I got firebase working in the unity. These are basically snapshots I have taken during the process for record.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Download jar files from here if have trouble finding them](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l9rg8xghhrc7lsn/AndroidJars_dontdelete.zip?dl=0)

I hope this much information will be enough for you to get started. If you need any other information then please comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this files to the plugin/android folder: http://joxi.ru/Q2KeQD7C3zdYrj . after that your sdk will work fine.

P.S. I dont understand why log event doesn't work, maybe need to wait. I think, google json file will setting the app, but package name of sdk module and unity app package name need to equal