# Unity3d FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase

I'm trying to integrate Firebase on Unity3d in order to receive push notifications.

I get the following error when the app launching:

```
I/dalvikvm( 7881): Could not find method android.content.Context.isDeviceProtectedStorage, referenced from method com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza
I/FirebaseInitProvider( 7881): FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
```

The firebase-messaging sample work fine with my google-services.json. So I suppose that the console configuration is correct.

**1. I created a library project on Android Studio.**

I followed a web site to build a .jar from Android Studio and the official documentation to add firebase.

http://www.thegamecontriver.com/2015/04/android-plugin-unity-android-studio.html

project gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'src/main/java'
            }
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
    compile files('libs/classes.jar')
}

task deleteOldJar(type: Delete) {
    delete 'release/NotificationPlugin.jar'
}

task exportJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('release/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar', 'NotificationPlugin.jar')
}

exportJar.dependsOn(deleteOldJar, build)

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

At this point a .jar is successfully generated.

**2. I created a JarResolver dependencies in Unity.**

I use the PlayServicesResolver v1.1 found into other google unity package (Google analytics for exemple, other plugins upgrade it)

https://github.com/googleanalytics/google-analytics-plugin-for-unity

FirebaseDependencies.cs

```
using Google.JarResolver;
using UnityEditor;

[InitializeOnLoad]
public static class FirebaseDependencies
{
    private static readonly string PluginName = "Firebase";

    static FirebaseDependencies()
    {
        PlayServicesSupport svcSupport = PlayServicesSupport.CreateInstance(
                                         PluginName,
                                         EditorPrefs.GetString("AndroidSdkRoot"),
                                         "ProjectSettings");

        svcSupport.DependOn("com.google.firebase",
            "firebase-core",
            PluginVersion.PlayServicesVersionConstraint);

        svcSupport.DependOn("com.google.firebase",
            "firebase-messaging",
            PluginVersion.PlayServicesVersionConstraint);
    }
}
```

PluginVersion.cs

```
public class PluginVersion
{
    public const string PlayServicesVersionConstraint = "9.6+";
}
```

After the ResolveClientJars command, all dependencies are copy into the Plugins/Android folder.

```
AndroidManifest.xml
firebase-analytics-9.6.1
firebase-analytics-impl-9.6.1
firebase-common-9.6.1
firebase-core-9.6.1
firebase-iid-9.6.1
firebase-messaging-9.6.1
google-services.json
play-services-basement-9.6.1
play-services-tasks-9.6.1
support-annotations-24.0.0.jar
support-v4-24.0.0
```

Everything seems to work perfectly at this point and there are no error during the build process.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try moving the google-services.json into the streaming assets folder? The problem could be that it cannot find that file

Comment: when using firebase in android studio you have to make sure that file is in the root of the app module, so perhaps it is not in the right place when unity exports

Comment: everything else looks correct to me

Comment: I moved the google-services.json into the StreamingAssets folder but I have the same error

Comment: I follow this thread and it works!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497363/google-firebase-analytics-plugin-for-unity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Firebase Push Notifications without creation additional plugin. But the flow is a little bit tricky. Here are quick steps:

1. In the Unity Editor. In the Build Settings select Google Android
   Project flag and Export your project. Make sure that your bundle id
   correspond to the bundle id  at the Firebase Console.
2. In the Android Studio. Import your Unity project. IMPORTANT: Don't
       Open, Import!
3. Setup .gradle scripts and add google-services.json file as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience).
4. Build project from Android Studio.