# Making a Google sign in plugin for Unity

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, plugins, google-identity

So I'm trying to get a [google sign in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start) working for Unity

I'm stuck however.

I'm trying to convert an [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/signin) into a Android library, which would call the sign in intent.

I've tried searching but with no leads.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497363/google-firebase-analytics-plugin-for-unity) shows that you need to extract all the extra libraries and add them to your unity project, seems like a good lead.

If anyone has done it, could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your question title is a little ambiguous, do you want to make your own plugin, or just implement Google sign-in in your game using a plugin?

Comment: There is no plugin for unity to implement Google Sign In, so I'm trying to create my own plugin. I'm  learning bit by bit at the moment, but there's not much info about android plugin creation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Firebase Authentication for Unity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/start) to add Google sign-in. It's easy to implement with examples on their page, and you can also add Facebook, email, and other other sign-in services. I highly recommend trying out some of their other products like Analytics too.

Comment: It doesn't work like that you need to actually call the Google sign in from the java side. I've done it now.

Comment: Perhaps you could leave your solution as an answer for others with the same problem?

Comment: What you need to do is implement google sign in in java and make it a library, when from unity call the function into the library.